# Firebase data not being recorded after changing GoogleService-Info.plist file name

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using both Firebase analytics and Google analytics in the same app to log events and get screen view data (side note: I thought firebase did this automatically but I don't see any screen view data anywhere on the dashboard).

Both Firebase and Google Analytics require me to add a GoogleService-Info.plist file into the project to be able to configure the analytics settings for each service. Since these files will cause a naming conflict I decide to rename the firebase one to GoogleFirebaseService-Info.plist and configure it like this:

```
let firbaseOptions = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleFirebaseService-Info", ofType: "plist"))
    FIRApp.configure(with: firbaseOptions!)
```

However, now only GA records screen data, but im not getting and event logs on the firebase console.

What is the correct way to integrate both services into a single project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/) to integrate both **Firebase Analytics** and **Google Analytics** in your app.

Please refer to [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en#firebase-ga) provided by **Google Help** for details.

Hope this helps!